# showing decimal separators on line numbers in VIM

Tags: vim

Is there any way for VIM to show "12.345" or "12 345" instead of "12345" on the line number columns? Or even better, to use different colors for the thousands?

Going over a big log, jumping from search term to search term, sometimes it is hard to see meaningful changes at a glance.

Comment: not possible without changing the c source of vim